# PHP API request by GET details

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the details from this example (i created the code right now).
But i'm very... confused... how can i get the details of the link, then separate and send to my MYSQL database..

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
    echo $e;
} 
else {
    $decoded = json_decode($resp, true);
    //print_r($decoded);
    foreach($decoded as $key => $item) {
        
        $array = array(
            'id' => ,
            'email' => ,
            'first_name' => ,
            'last_name' => ,
        );
        
        print_r($array);
    }
}

curl_close($ch);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

If you call the url in your browser then you will see that the result array is present in the `data` field.

You may check this by printing the whole result:

```
  print_r($decoded);
```

So if you like to print_r the results it should be simply

```
  print_r($decoded['data']);
```

If you like to store it in your database you may walk through the array and store each item

```
foreach($decoded['data'] as $item) {
    
    storeItem($item);

}
```

To make this work you should implement the `storeItem` function which accepts the `array $item` and stores it into your database. There are various tutorials about doing that.